# Showing subset of projects on landing page

Tags: sonarqube

I just upgraded to SonarQube to version 6.2. And as I did not carefully read the Upgrade Notes (my bad), I discovered that dashboards are removed (sad move, though).

Now, is there a way of showing a subset of all projects on a separate page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After logging in to 6.2 you land on the 'My Projects' page, which displays projects you've marked as favorites.